# Функция для выполнения команд через командную строку от имени администратора

Tags: python, cmd, windows-10

Нужно на Python создать функцию, которая бы выполняла команды в CMD Windows. Проблема в том, что она требует запуска от имени администратора.

Как выполнить `mkdir`, но чтобы окна CMD не было?

Пароля от пользователя нет, но действия происходят на админе.

Comment: *она требует запуска от имени администратора.* `RUNAS /USER:имя_пользователя команда`. *чтобы окно cmd не вылезало* Совсем без окна нельзя. Но можно запускать, сделав окно скрытым.

Comment: Спасибо, а что значит скрытым?

Comment: Эммм... ну невидимым... не отображаемым ни на экране, ни на панели задач. Т.е. оно-то есть, но его как бы и нет.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую